# how to download a file from a sibling directory in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component which I need to download a static file I have in an adjacent folder, I've tried loading the file using

```
import myFile from '../../myfile/myfile.pdf'

<Button onClick={(evt) => this.handleDownload(evt)}><a href={myFile} download="My_File.pdf">Temp Download BTN</a></Button>
```

but when I try to import that, it throws the error below

```
Cannot find module '../../myfile/myfile.pdf' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should tell to typescript to resolve pdf files
Try to create file `../../myfile/index.d.ts` with the content

```
declare module "*.pdf" {
  const value: any;
  export = value;
}
```

Comment: still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `declaration.d.ts` file in the root of the folder

```
declare module '*.pdf' {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```

Comment: still the same error